# Anime movie: kid is so good at VR game that government tries to recruit him

Tags: story-identification, anime

We were discussing [the mandela effect](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-mandela-effect) at work today, and a coworker insisted he saw an anime movie around 2000-2001 that he could never find ever again.

According to him:

- It had a very similar style to Akira (especially the motorbikes), however it doesn't show up on the history of the studio or artists behind Akira
- The opening scene was a futuristic arcade, where a group of kids went to play a VR game
- Most of the kids were bad at the game, but one kid was exceptionally good
- He was so good that the government hacked into the game to talk to him, and tried to recruit him into working for them, presumably piloting mechs or something similar.
- Post apocalyptic
- City is out in a desert somewhere
- Motorbikes turn into robots
- There was a girl in a "tube" (like a stasis tube, filled with a fluid of some kind)

Will update if I get any more info from him.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Mayube! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question (by asking your co-worker, possibly), so that it will be easier for others to find the anime that you are searching for.

Comment: This kind of reminds me of an episode of Outlaw Star, although it is mostly in space. From what I remember(it has been awhile), one of the characters, Jim finds an arcade and kids his own age to talk to. He proceeds to beat all of them at some game. Don't remember government involvement, and not exactly post apocalyptic.  One character does navigate the ship from a tube.

Comment: Maybe your co-worker also fell victim to the Mandela Effect.

Comment: Huh, that sounds really familiar. I think I saw a movie like that on fox kid's like 16 or 17 years ago. I can't for the life of me remember what it's called.

Comment: The movie was probably [The Last Starfighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter), but that's live action, not anime.  It was from 1984 and has been lampooned a number of times.

Comment: Other than the motorbikes, this sounds a lot like Zegapain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm **[Megazone 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megazone_23)**, an OVA from the late 80s that got re-released in 2004! You seem to be looking for Part 3.

You want bikes from Akira that transform into robots? I have bikes from Akira that transform into robots!

[image: Akira-esque bike]
[image: More bike, more unishade]

Also DO NOT FORGET MY LOVE.

We've got an apocalypse and excelling at video games!

> **Megazone 23 Part III** takes place some unspecified number of centuries after the **apocalyptic ending of Megazone 23 Part II**. People now live in a highly advanced city called Eden, where an
>   organization called EX controls every aspect of the city and strongly
>   polices the activity in the network which serves as Eden’s nervous
>   system. Overseeing EX is a mysterious figure called Reverend Wong Dai,
>   who has to deal with hackers constantly try to invade the system and
>   uncover the secrets he is trying to keep from the citizens of Eden.
>   This prompts EX to seek out talented young programmers to combat the
>   hackers in a digital duel. **The spotlight shines on Eiji Takanaka, a
>   young gamer/software programmer/geek who lives for the arcades,
>   playing the intense, virtual reality shoot’em up called “Hard On”**

We've got...wait, what?

[image: Super Game Hard On!]

Ah! Checks out. Okay!

We probably have a girl in a tube around here somewhere, but honestly I'm not sure. *Seems* like something we'd have. Oh! Got one in an egg!

[image: Eggs are like tubes]

Sitting in the fridge the whole time! I knew we had one around here somewhere!

**Sources:**

My own flawed memory

[Anime of Yesteryear Podcast](https://aoypodcast.com/tag/megazone-23/)

[Hardcore Gaming 101 Anime Reviews](http://hg101.proboards.com/thread/261/anime-reviews?page=11)

Comment: I pitched this to my co-worker and he said this very well could be it!